# How to integrate the HAVING clause after GROUP BY CASE

Tags: mysql

I have the following query working fine, but need to filter out ages in records that have their status set to "Invalid" or "Archived". My table is named Contact, and has a status column and an age column. Other statuses are Active, Follow Up, and Completed.

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN age BETWEEN '0' AND '18' THEN '18 and Under'   
  WHEN  age BETWEEN '19' AND '30' THEN '19 to 30'   
  WHEN age BETWEEN '31' AND '40' THEN '31 to 40'   
  WHEN  age BETWEEN '41' AND '50' THEN '41 to 50'   
  WHEN age BETWEEN '51' AND '60' THEN '51 to 60'                             
  ELSE '61 and Older'
  END
 ,Count(id)
FROM  Contact
GROUP BY 
CASE
  WHEN age BETWEEN '0' AND '18' THEN '18 and Under'   
  WHEN  age BETWEEN '19' AND '30' THEN '19 to 30'   
  WHEN age BETWEEN '31' AND '40' THEN '31 to 40'   
  WHEN  age BETWEEN '41' AND '50' THEN '41 to 50'   
  WHEN age BETWEEN '51' AND '60' THEN '51 to 60'                             
  ELSE '61 and Older'
END
```

I am trying to integrate the HAVING clause as follows, but not sure where to put it:

```
HAVING status NOT IN('Invalid', 'Archived')
```

Everywhere I try gives an error. Any help to get pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that the error may be coming from an invalid `GROUP BY`

Comment: Try `FROM  Contact WHERE status NOT IN('Invalid', 'Archived') GROUP BY...`. Not sure if this will work though.

Comment: Use `group by 1` (column number reference). No need to repeat the entire case clause.

Comment: Thanks Jim! Worked a treat... I tried your suggestion and it worked to shorten the query. How would I use the Having clause I am referenced above?

Comment: you can add a `as age_range` to the end of your `CASE ... END` and `GROUP BY age_range` instead of having your code doubled, it's bad if you have to change it in future you have to change it in two places, see my answer you'll see what i mean

Comment: @Jim I didn't know you can do `group by 1` column number reference. ha ya learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 1):

try this [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be9ef/7/0)

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN age BETWEEN  '0' AND '18' THEN '18 and Under'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '19' AND '30' THEN '19 to 30'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '31' AND '40' THEN '31 to 40'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '41' AND '50' THEN '41 to 50'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '51' AND '60' THEN '51 to 60'                             
        ELSE '61 and Older'
       END as age_range,
       status,
       Count(id) as `count`
FROM  Contact
WHERE status NOT IN ('Invalid','Archived')
GROUP BY age_range,status;
```

or if you wish to use the `HAVING status NOT IN ('Invalid','Archived')`, you can use the below it's the same end result as the above. ([sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be9ef/8/0))

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN age BETWEEN  '0' AND '18' THEN '18 and Under'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '19' AND '30' THEN '19 to 30'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '31' AND '40' THEN '31 to 40'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '41' AND '50' THEN '41 to 50'   
        WHEN age BETWEEN '51' AND '60' THEN '51 to 60'                             
        ELSE '61 and Older'
       END as age_range,
       status,
       Count(id) as `count`
FROM  Contact
GROUP BY age_range,status
HAVING status NOT IN ('Invalid','Archived');
```

Comment: I can see that your example works perfectly in sqlfiddle. I am running this as a Native SQL query in Wavemaker's query editor, and I am getting this error "Run query error: MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'age_range' in 'group statement'. Most queries run fine in Wavemaker but some fail for some reason.